# Python - set list range to a specific value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need to set a subset of a list to a specific value based on a tuple with bounds `(start,end)`.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
indexes = range(bounds[0], bounds[1] + 1)
for i in indexes:
   my_list[i] = 'foo'
```

This doesn't seem good to me. Is there a more pythonic approach?

Comment: You can use slice assignment, but I think your method is fine.  By the way, the plural of index is _indices_.

Comment: Honestly, they way you're doing it is fine and readable, I don't think that compressing it down to one line adds anything.

Comment: @wim, I too prefer _indices_, but most modern dictionaries recognize both as acceptable.

Comment: @wim I think 'indexes' might be more common in US/Canada, whereas 'indices' is more common in the UK/Oz

Comment: Just to re-emphasise a point, I would consider the way you are doing it in your question more pythonic than the answers using slice assignment. The zen of python states, "simple is better than complex". You're just setting several elements of a list to a value, there is no need for slice assignment there, all that is doing is introducing more scope for bugs by making you calculate more values (through the generation of the array that you are assigning through). Keep what you have.

Comment: I reckon that there is no reason to have a variable named `indexes` in the first place. You only need it once so just plug it into the for loop.

Comment: @AndrewBarett I actually agree with you on this case, this just looks complicated since there is an unnecessary assignment to indexes variable which makes it longer than it needs to be.

EDIT: As long as the bounds can be presumed to actually exist in the list.

Comment: @armandino You should submit your own code as an answer and accept it, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use slice assignment:

```
my_list[bounds[0]:bounds[1] + 1] = ['foo'] * ((bounds[1] + 1) - bounds[0])
```

or using local variables to add your `+ 1` only once:

```
lower, upper = bounds
upper += 1
my_list[lower:upper] = ['foo'] * (upper - lower)
```

You may want to store the upper bound as non-inclusive, to play better with python and avoid all the `+ 1` counts.

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = range(10)
>>> bounds = (2, 5)
>>> my_list[bounds[0]:bounds[1] + 1] = ['foo'] * ((bounds[1] + 1) - bounds[0])
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: +1 to "store the upper bound as non-inclusive." n + 1 bugs are a huge pain.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> L = list("qwerty")
>>> L
['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']
>>> L[2:4] = ["foo"] * (4-2)
>>> L
['q', 'w', 'foo', 'foo', 't', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more efficient version of the solution by @MartijnPieters using `itertools.repeat`

```
import itertools
lower, upper = bounds
upper += 1
my_list[lower:upper] = itertools.repeat('foo', (upper - lower))
```