# Python. Replace elements using slice

Tags: python, list, replace, slice

I need to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.
I have list:
`bar = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I need to replace each odd element with "0".
Now I have code:

```
while viewIndex < maxNumber:
    bar[viewIndex] = 0
    viewIndex += 2
```

But I remember about slices. And for me it will be nice to write something like this:

```
bar[currentIndex::2] = 0
```

But I have error:

```
TypeError: must assign iterable to extended slice
```

Maybe you know a beautiful solution to this task.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395057/python-set-list-range-to-a-specific-value

Comment: If you're looking to build a Sieve of Eatosthenes, there is one [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/). Not sure what you seek to accomplish simply by skipping the odd indices. The Sieve will take care of all things for you.

Comment: numpy lets you do this directly. would be nice if core python did too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign the slice to an iterable of the same length as the number of odds:

```
bar[1::2] = [0]*(len(bar)//2)
print(bar)
# [2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

To extend this for *even* indices, you need to take into consideration lists with odd-lengths (not relevant for the above case) by adding the modulo 2 value of the list length:

```
bar[::2] = [0]*(len(bar)//2 + len(bar)%2)
```

Which is same as:

```
bar[::2] = [0]*sum(divmod(len(bar), 2))
```

Comment: What does the `::` do? Not familiar with that.

Comment: @pstatix Python's slice syntax: `start:stop:stride`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use the `::` though do you? A single `:` will work, at least it appears so in the post from @RoachLord.

Comment: @pstatix you need it: slice starts at index 1, goes to the end (omitted, hence consecutive colons), in steps of 2. Equivalent to `bar[1:len(bar):2]`

Comment: @schwobaseggl Excellent, got it.

Comment: @pstatix if you use a single `:` you will end up with something like `[2,0,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: @schwobaseggl You don't need to take the slice on the right hand only for `len`; pretty expensive for large lists.

Comment: This solution seeks to change odd numbered _indices_ does it not? I get how it functions, but I thought the question asked for odd _elements_, regardless of their index.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Still linear, but you are totally right. The `divmod` solution is, of course, much cheaper: `(0 for _ in [x]range(0, len(bar), 2))` on the rhs would be another cheap and slightly less cryptic option, directly communicating the same length property.

Comment: @pstatix Did you read the code by the OP? It increments the index in twos not the elements.

Comment: I did read the code, but I also read the text! OP asked for _elements_ not _indices_. Either way, they have hopefully learned a lot, I learned more about the slice operator.

Comment: @pstatix You are right, but the code example the OP is giving suggests that he means odd indexes.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I still find building a list from `range` in Python 2 inconvenient. I think you have a typo.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Hence the `[x]range` to cover both versions. Typo?

Comment: This doesn't work if an odd number is next to another odd number.

Comment: @srig They are working with indices not elements in the lists.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Sorry, with all types of brackets carrying syntactic meaning in Python, I was running out of marker chars ;-)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

I use numpy:

```
foo = np.ones(10)
foo[1::2] = 2
```

This just works.

You shouldn't have to keep track of indices -- the point of slicing is to make things *more* convenient, not to force you to keep track of which day of the week relative to the third Tuesday of last month you bought bread.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple for loop

```
bar = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in  range(len(bar)):
   if bar[i] % 2 != 0:
       bar[i] = 0
print(bar)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to set elements on odd index to zero,

```
bar = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print map(lambda i: 0 if bar.index(i)%2!=0 else i, bar)

[2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

or if you want to set odd element value to zero, you can do this,

```
map(lambda i: 0 if i%2!=0 else i, bar)
```

Comment: In your case as a result I will have iterator. But I need list

Comment: What version of python are you using? i am sure i you are using python 2, map returns a `list` type not iterator.

Comment: Now I use python 3.5 but I have read books about python 2. Thank you a lot for answer!

Comment: You can explicitly convert a map object to list like `list(map(lambda i: 0 if i%2!=0 else i, bar))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all for answers. My implementation of Sieve of Eatosthenes algorithm:

```
def resheto(data): 
     print("\tStart Resheto") 
     currentIndex = 0 

     while currentIndex < len(data) - 1: 
         data[currentIndex + data[currentIndex]::data[currentIndex]] = \
             [0] * ((len(data) + 1) // data[currentIndex] - 1) 
         currentIndex += 1 

         while currentIndex < len(data) - 1 and data[currentIndex] == 0: 
             currentIndex += 1 

         if currentIndex >= len(data) - 1: 
             break 
print("\tEnd Resheto") return data
```