# Pythonic way to add the same value in a list in one line?

Tags: python, list

I want to add the number zero in a range of a list in a one line loop.

Basically what I want to do is this but in one line:

```
for position in range(43,53):
    rows[0][position] = 0
```

What I tried is this but I don't think it's correct:

```
rows[0][0 for position in range(43, 54)]
```

Comment: Something like `rows[0][43:53] = [0] * (53-43)`. There might be some off-by-one error here...

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? What is `rows` can you provide an example? Can you provide an example of your desired result? Why do you need it in *one line*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - set list range to a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395057/python-set-list-range-to-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a slice:

```
rows[0][43:53] = [0 for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Or just `rows[0][43:53] = [0] * 10`

Comment: Or itertools.repeat as in the other answer. Many ways to make an iterable of 0s.

Comment: The comprehension is safer in general, for values that aren't, like 0, immutable.

Comment: @chepner Why is that?

Comment: @MichaelKolber Try `x = [[3]] * 10`, then set `x[0][0] = 10` and see what `x` looks like afterwords.

Comment: @chepner I see, each `[3]` refers to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice assignment. `repeat` creates a sequence of 0s of the necessary length.

```
rows[0][43:53] = itertools.repeat(0, 10)
```

(I'm mainly using `repeat` because I erroneously thought that `list.__setitem__` would only try to consume as many elements as necessary to fill the desired range. That appears to be false, though in general, one could implement `__setitem__` to be that lazy, in which case you could simply write `whatever[43:54] = itertools.repeat(0)`, and you wouldn't have to precompute the number of 0s required.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. plus look at the other posted solutions

```
rows[0][43:53] = [0] * 10
```